# How to access the local files to restore in remotely accessed PgAdmin4 in centos 8

Tags: php, postgresql, centos8, postgresql-15

I have one Web Server with PHP and one Database Server with PostgreSQL 15. Both with Cent OS 8. I have installed pgadmin4 in the web server to access the Remote Database server through browser and it's accessible.

Now with the help of PgAdmin4 I can create database or tables in the Database Server. But when I tried to do database backup using the pgadmin4 web browser, the file selection dialog shows nothing and if anyhow I try to access it and create it shows **Access Denied**.

[image]

Same case with the Restore option also if I click on the Restore Option the file selection dialog shows nothing to select from the file to restore.

I think that I might have missed some configuration, I searched a lot on google but without any success. How can I solve this issue, please help.

Comment: This does not look related to programming to me - or did you write any code on your own that triggers the problem?

Comment: yes its not related to programming